# Converting a raster to a csv in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, r-raster

I wish to convert a raster to a csv file. I have tried to convert a raster to a dataframe on one file just to see if it works. I have tried  using:

```
as.data.frame( rasterToPoints(species) )
```

but I get an error when I try to write "species" to a csv :

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("RasterLayer", package = "raster")"   to a data.frame
```

This is my code (I need to convert multiple rasters to csv (see the loop))

```
#start loop
file.names <- dir(path, pattern=".csv")

for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file<- read.csv(file.name[i], header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#subsetting each file and renaming column header names
sub.file<-subset(file, select = c('Matched.Scientific.Name',  'Vernacular.Name...matched', 'Latitude...processed', 'Longitude...processed'))
names(sub.file) <- c('species', 'name', 'Lat','Lon')

#turn into a SpatialPointsDataFrame 
coordinates(sub.file) <- ~ Lon + Lat 
proj4string(sub.file) <- '+init=EPSG:4326'
plot(sub.file, axes=TRUE)

#converting to BNG
sub.file.BNG <- spTransform(sub.file, '+init=EPSG:27700')
plot(sub.file.BNG, axes=TRUE)

#creating template raster
template <- raster(xmn=400000, xmx=600000, ymn=200000, ymx=800000,  res=25000, crs='+init=EPSG:27700')

#point data > presence grid
species <- rasterize(sub.file.BNG, template, field=1)
plot(species)

# UK wide
template <- raster(xmn=-200000, xmx=700000, ymn=0, ymx=1250000, res=25000, crs='+init=EPSG:27700')

# use that to turn species point data into a presence grid
species <- rasterize(sub.file, template, field=1)
plot(species)

#converting a raster>dataframe>csv?????
as.data.frame( rasterToPoints(species) )
}
```

Comment: You need to assign `as.data.frame( rasterToPoints(species) )` to an object and then save that object as a CSV.

Comment: raster objects can generally be converted to a matrix.  Maybe try just doing that and see if the matrix can be converted to the data frame you need. Go to section 5.4 of this vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Always provide some example data when asking a question.

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
```

To get the cell values

```
x <- as.data.frame(r)
head(x, 2)
#  test
#1   NA
#2   NA
```

To get the cell coordinates and values, only for cells that are not NA

```
x <- rasterToPoints(r) 
head(x, 2)
#         x      y    test
#[1,] 181180 333740 633.686
#[2,] 181140 333700 712.545
```

To get the cell coordinates and values, only for all cells (including NA)

```
x <- cbind(coordinates(r), v=values(r))
head(x, 2)
#          x      y  v
#[1,] 178420 333980 NA
#[2,] 178460 333980 NA
```

Whichever one you choose, you can then do

```
write.csv(x, "test.csv")
```

The mistake you made is that you did not assign the result of `as.data.frame` to a variable, and then tried to write the RasterLayer with `write.csv`. That is an error, and you get

```
write.csv(r)
#Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
# cannot coerce class ‘structure("RasterLayer", package = "raster")’ to a 
# data.frame
```

By the way, if you have multiple rasters, you may want to combine them first

```
s <- stack(r, r, r)
x <- rasterToPoints(s) 
head(x, 2)
#          x      y  test.1  test.2  test.3
#[1,] 181180 333740 633.686 633.686 633.686
#[2,] 181140 333700 712.545 712.545 712.545
write.csv(x, "test.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your raster is "species"

```
 species<- raster("C:/.../species.tif")
```

To perform this conversion, it is necessary to take the values of each pixel: X coordinates (1), Y coordinates (2) and own values of each cell (3).

```
 # don't run these lines
 #(1) = coordinates (species) [, 1]
 #(2) = coordinates (species) [, 2]
 #(3) = values (species)
```

Having these expressions we can add them to a dataframe as follows

```
dat<- data.frame("X"=coordinates(species)[,1],"Y"=coordinates(species) 
[,2],"Values"=values(species))
```